# How to prevent Angular Signal references being used instead of Signal Values?

Tags: angular, signals, typescript-eslint, angular17, angular-signals

I am enthralled with Angular Signals, exactly what I want out of the library, but one thing that I have commonly found is that I accidentally am calling a signal reference somewhere (in a template block, or in the component somewhere) instead of calling the signal value. For example:

```
public conditionalSignal = signal(false);
...

// Accidentally using the reference:
if (conditionalSignal) {
  ...
}

// Instead of something like this:
if (conditionalSignal()) {
  ...
}
```

I was hoping someone had a ESLint plugin or Angular compiler option that they knew about that would help prevent this situation from happening. This obviously doesn't occur when I am generating new signals, but when refactoring old components to use a signal based methodology, it has happened more than once, and it's something that I would like to prevent if at all possible.

I also recognize that my first example is completely valid code, but I can almost guarantee that I'd never do that intentionally.

Comment: That could be a feature request on `angular-eslint`, to throw an error when a signal isn't invoked  in a condition

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler that was exactly my thought as well if something like this didn't already exist. I was hoping that the community would come through, but I'll go submit a request on their repository and see what they say.